# Range for identifier, when matching data frames

Tags: r, merge, range, intervals

I would need to match two data frames based on two different identifiers, which are *date* and *id*, in the example below. However, I would need to set "range for the identifier": `new_df <- merge(df1 , df2 , by = c(id , date +-1 day interval)` This new data frame should have all the observations that have occured within the `[-1, +1]` interval.

The first data below have values for every day and I would just need to drop observations that are not within this mentioned interval. The "zero"-day would be in the second data frame (`df2`).

//first data:

```
id <- c(a56 , a56 , a56 ,a56 ..., a1782)
date <-(1990-04-07 , 1990-04-08 , 1990-04-09 , 1990-04-10, ... , 1994-08-19)
value <- (0.003 , 0.023 , 0.127 , 0.278 , 0.378, ... ,0.378)
df1 <- data.frame(id ,date)
```

//Second data:

```
 id <- c(a56 , a78 , a99 , a101, a1893 , a167 , a1782)
 date <-c(1990-04-10 , 1990-08-18 , 1990-10-17, 1991-04-10 , 1994-08-18 ,1995-10-17)
 df2 <- data.frame(id , date)
```

desired output would following:

```
1. a56  1990-04-09  0.278
2. a56  1990-04-10  0.378
3. a56  1990-04-11  0.444 .....
9999. a1782 1994-08-18  0.345
1000. a17882 1994-08-19 0.378
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I run your lines of code exactly-as-is above, it produces a `df1` with nothing in it, and does not produce a `df2`. Can you include the other data that this example requires please so that the problem is reproducible? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So I'm kinda guessing what your data looks like, since the sample code you gave doesn't entirely work (please double check next time).

Note that I cast the dates to `Date`.

All I do here is join the two dataframes *only* on `id`, so I preserve both date columns. I filter the dates from `df1` to be within the +/-1 interval of the date from `df2`, then I drop the `df1` date column.

```
id <- c('a56', 'a56', 'a56', 'a56', 'a1782')
date <- as.Date(c('1990-04-07' , '1990-04-08' , '1990-04-09' , '1990-04-10', '1994-08-19'))
value <- c(0.003 , 0.023 , 0.127 , 0.278, 0.378)
df1 <- data.frame(id ,date, value)
id <- c('a56' , 'a78' , 'a99' , 'a101', 'a1893' , 'a167')
date <- as.Date(c('1990-04-10' , '1990-08-18' , '1990-10-17', '1991-04-10' , '1994-08-18' ,'1995-10-17'))
df2 <- data.frame(id , date)

df = merge(df1, df2, by = 'id', suffixes = c('', '.y'))
df = df[df$date >= df$date.y - 1 & df$date <= df$date.y +1, 1:3]
```

I get:

```
   id       date value
3 a56 1990-04-09 0.127
4 a56 1990-04-10 0.278
```